# How to display an image from desktop on plnkr.co

Tags: javascript, html, plunker

I need to display something on plunker which is from my desktop for security reasons, I just want to take a screen shot and dispose of the image basically.

I am trying

```
<img src="file///C:/users/me/desktop/img1.jpg">
```

also tried without file///, is this possible with plunker?

Comment: The image would need to exist on a publicly accessible webserver in order for plnkr to see it.

Comment: What is the purpose of using plunker specifically for the screenshot? You can take a screenshot of an image many other ways.

Comment: for a mock up, and thanks j08691

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your HTML documents **in the same folder as the image** and change the img tag to something like `<img src="img.png" alt="" />`.

Or you could also add folders to the file
path if it is stored deeper in the main folder ( or database ).

**EDIT:** For plunker use, it can't be done. It must be hosted online (such as a hosting service like imgur), otherwise there is no way the HTML can call it.